# How to produce Multiple Maven Artifacts from one Source

Tags: maven, artifacts

I understand that this is against maven best practices, but maybe my situation is one of the few exceptions from the rule - at least I'm stuck with thinking of alternatives :(

The environment is this:

- we have a legacy application with proprietary technology based interfaces to the outside world
- we want to use flash as the new frontend
- based on the legacy interface we generate flash classes and package them in a flash swc to be used by the frontend developers
- based on the legacy interface we generate java classes which bridge the flash service requests (coming via blazeds) to our legacy interface
- to make it more difficult, we don't want to / can't use a pom on it's own for each interface as we have dozens of them (interfaces) and they would only differ in their artifactId. Instead I use a "generic" project structure which will get parameterized (by jenkins) for each build. The project will *only* be used in an fully automated environment.

First I've tried to put all these in one "simple" project, which works up to the point where the artifacts should get installed.

My current approach is a multimodule project structure inspired by maven reference chapter 13, which has some disadvantages on it's own:

```
GenericProject
|
+-- GenerateSources from legacy interface
|   +-- pom.xml
|
+-- Java 
|   +-- pom.xml
|
+-- SWC 
|   +-- pom.xml
|
+-- pom.xml
```

This approach has the disadvantage, that I have references from "Java" & "SWC" to the internal structure of "GenerateSource" which is ugly but tolerable.
**What really gets in my way** is that I have to heavily tweak the install & the deploy plugins to get artifacts with the name & version of the legacy interface which triggered the whole process.
I got it running now, but it looks very brittle.

I considered splitting/duplicating the project in two simple projects:

- GenerateSources & Java
- GenerateSources & SWC

But this would only solve the minor annoyance with the cross-references.

As Aaron pointed out in his comment, I'm unclear in stating the problem.
After some more experiments this got a lot clearer to me:
Essentially I have two problems to solve

1. install/deploy two artifacts together
2. name the artifacts different than the `project.artifactId`

Any suggestions to make the whole process more maven-like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should split the question into more simple and more specific ones. Right now, I'm not sure what your problem is. Do you know about the JAR plugin which allows to create more artifacts during the build? Do you know about the options to specify the name(s) of the final artifacts? What exactly do you mean by "references to the internal structure"?

Comment: Hi Aaron, in my single-project-approach, I already set the project.build.finalName to "${Interface-Name}-${Interface-Verion}" and

Comment: [soory, wong key] . . . it get's honored by the JAR plugin so that I get a "Interface-Name-Interface-Version.jar". But both install and deploy plugin insist on using project.artifactId for their purpose. In addition, the differentiation between snapshot and release is also based in project.version instead of ${Interface-Version} as I would need it.

Comment: With "references to the internal structure" I mean that I generate Java-Sources in module GenerateSource to src/main/java-gen and access them via "project.build.sourceDirectory=../Java/src/main/java-gen" from module Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some detours with the multimodule approach I came to the following pragmatic solution:

1. use the `build-helper-plugin` to attach a secondary artifact to be installed/deployed automaticly
2. two-phase build:

   2.1 generate a pom.xml via `sed` which contains resolved `project.artifactId` & `project.version`

   2.2 run the maven build

Although you theoretically can use expressions as `project.artifactId` & `project.version`, maven gives you a warning for this . . . for a good reason: 
When you try to reference the produced artifacts, nexus will give you a "Failed to read artifact descriptor for . . ." error. 
I suspect this is because in the stored pom in the repository the expressions are unresolved!

Answer (score 2):

You should write a small Maven plugin that you attach to the `generate-sources` phase. See the [maven-annotation-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) for an example ([main class](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/source/browse/trunk/processor/src/main/java/org/bsc/maven/plugin/processor/MainAnnotationProcessorMojo.java)).

That will include the generated sources in the output of the `GenerateSource` and you can consume those classes just by including the dependency in the other POMs. Note that you should create those files under `target/`, not in `src/`.

As for install/deploy: Those plugins get their names from the plugins which create artifacts. So there must be something wrong with how you set the property. In your case, that's the [JAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html). The documentation has an example how to [set the name of the default artifact](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using Maven overlays, it's used to share resources between multiple web applications.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

Comment: Thx for the link, but as I understand the description, overlays are specific to the war-plugin which is not applicable in my situation.